# How to alternately append elements from two lists to one?

Tags: python, list

I have two files, the first one has first and second names and the other has first and last names. There's a line for one person in each file and they're in the same order. The names are separated by \t. For example the first line of the first file is Jake\tSmith and the first line of the second file is Jake\tArthur. I need to save the peoples full names to a list. The first name on my list would then be Jake\tArthur\tSmith. I hope this made any sense.

This is my code so far:

```
first_and_second_names= open(file1, "r")
first_and_last_names = open(file2, "r")

lines1 = first_and_second_names.readlines()
lines2 = first_and_last_names.readlines()

list = []

for x in lines1:
  for y in lines2:
    data = x.split("\t")
    data2 = y.split("\t")
    first_name = data2[0]
    second_name = data[1]
    last_name = (data2[1])
    list.append(first_mane + "\t" + second_name + "\t" + last_name + "\n")
    continue
```

The problem i have is that all the people in my list have the same second name (Arthur). I thought adding continue to the end of my inner loop would help me but it seems nothing changed. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip function like this;

```
first_and_second_names= open(file1, "r")
first_and_last_names = open(file2, "r")

lines1 = first_and_second_names.readlines()
lines2 = first_and_last_names.readlines()

list = []

for x, y in zip(lines1, lines2):
    data = x.split("\t")
    data2 = y.split("\t")
    first_name = data2[0]
    second_name = data[1]
    last_name = data2[1]
    list.append(first_name + "\t" + second_name + "\t" + last_name + "\n")
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution isn't pretty but it will do the job, especially if you only need to do it once.

```
['\t'.join([*name1.split('\t'), name2.split('\t')[1]]) 
    for name1, name2 in list(zip(first_second, first_last))]
```

list(zip(...)) alternates elements from the two lists, such that each element in that list is a pair of the two matching entries. The '\t'.join(...) will concatenate the bits of text in the ellipsis and separate them by tabs. The contents of the ellipsis is simply the enumeration of all three separate names. Overall, this uses list comprehension to generate a list 'on-the-fly'.

Here is another alternative:

```
list(map(
    lambda names: '\t'.join([*names[0].split('\t'), names[1].split('\t')[1]]), 
    zip(first_second, first_last)))
```